# Banach-Steinhaus theorem problem

Tags: functional-analysis

my problem is:

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ be linear noemed space and $T:X\rightarrow Y$ linear operation. if
> $$\{g(T(x))\, \, \vert \, \,  x\in B_{x}, \, \, g \in B_{Y^{*}}\}$$
> be bounded then $T$ is bounded and,
> $$||T||=\sup\{|g(T(x))|\, \, \vert \, \, x\in B_{x},\, \,  g \in B_{Y^{*}} \}$$
> note, $Y^{*}=B(Y,\mathbb{F})$ such that $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

My version of Banach-Steinhaus theorem is,

Let $X$ be a Banach space, let $Y$ be a normed space, and let $B(X,Y)$ be a set of continuous linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. Suppose that, for all $x∈X$, there exists $M>0$ such that, for all $T∈B(X,Y)$, we have $||T(x)||≤M$. Then there exists $K>0$ such that, for all $T∈B(X,Y)$, we have $||T||≤K$.

Comment: Your notation and goal are somewhat unclear.  You wrote $x \in B_x$ but $g \in B_{Y^*}$, which makes me suspect the former should have been $B_X$ instead.  Please edit for spelling and notation as necessary, and state in your own words what the goal of the Question is.  In its present form it does not strike me that you had clearly digested what problem you wanted help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you need the Banach - Steinhaus for this, your condition is strong enough to prove it without it. Let me remind you a nice corollary of the Hahn - Banach:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $x\in X$. Then there exists $x^*\in X^*$ with $||x^*||=1$ such that $x^*(x) = ||x||$.

Now, fix some $x\in B_X$. Using the above for the image $T(x)$ we may find $g_x \in Y^*$ with $||g_x||=1$ and $g_x(T(x))=||T(x)||$. Then by your hypothesis we know that  the set $\{g_x(T(x)):\, x\in B_X\}$ is bounded. But this set is equal to $\{||T(x)||\,:\, x\in B_X\}$ and therefore, it follows that
$$||T|| = \sup\{||T(x)||\,:\, x\in B_x\}<\infty.$$

**Edit** Proof of the equality
$$||T|| = \sup\{g(T(x))\,:\, g\in B_{Y^*},\, x\in B_X\}\tag{*}=:M.$$

Let $\epsilon>0$, then by sup's characterization there exists $g\in B_{Y^*},\, x\in B_X$ such that
$$M-\epsilon < g(T(x)).$$
Then,
$$M-\epsilon<|g(T(x))|\leq ||g||\cdot ||x||\cdot ||T|| = ||T||.$$
Therefore, $M-\epsilon<||T||$ for every $\epsilon>0$, which in turn implies that $M = ||T||$ and $(*)$ has been proven.